# Check if `git bisect` is active in a script, in a robist stable way?

Tags: git

If I start doing a git bisect, then the output of `git status` will show me that I am currently bisecting. I would like to perform this  “are you bisecting?” test in a script, I could look at the output of `git status`, but I suspect there is a better way. `git status --porcelain` doesn't include this bisecting status.

How can I robustly check in a script that a `git bisect` is currently active?

git version 2.25

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `git bisect log`.  This will produce output and/or errors, so redirect that away.
2. Test the status of the command when it finishes.  If you are in the middle of a bisect, the status will be zero, otherwise it will be nonzero.

Hence:

```
if git bisect log >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo bisection is in progress
else
    echo no bisection is in progress
fi
```

or:

```
if ! git bisect log >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo no bisection in progress; fi
```

(this is not documented but appears to be pretty reliable).